# How can I transform these triangles to $30-60-90$ triangles?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to transform the triangles below subject to a few constraints, and cannot figure out how (algebraically) to do so. For ease of notation, I'll refer to points like $E(C)$ as $C$. 
I want $CEF$ and $BEF$ to be $30-60-90$. I want to leave $E$ and $C$ fixed. Right now $ECF < 30$ and $EBF > 30$. 
How can I continuously transform the points of these triangles so the end results is to slide $F$ down (so that its $y$-coordinate is the same as $C$'s) and slide $B$ down and to the right so that $EBF = 30$, while preserving line segments inside each triangle? Bonus points if you can preserve line segments that cross between the two triangles (I think it's impossible). 
Ideally the solution would look something line $x' = f(x,y)$, $y' = g(x,y)$. I rotated and translated to get to the orientation below, because I suspected polar coordinates would help, but if it's easier to use some other starting point, that's fine.
Thanks!

[image: Triangles Before]

Comment: If I understand your constraints correctly, this is in general impossible. The only point $F'$ along the line $y=y_C$ that makes $\angle{CF'E}$ a right angle is $(x_E,y_C)$. If $2|y_E-y_C|\ne|x_E-x_C|$, the other two angles won’t have the measures that you want. It is possible to warp $\triangle{CEF}$ into the desired shape, but it will require displacing $F$ in the $x$-direction as well.

Comment: @Brian First.- Why do you want to transform these triangles? Second.- In a 30-60-90 triangle, sides are in proportion 1-Sqrt(3)-2. So maintaining C and E fixed, F will go down and a little to the left. Third.- With E fixed and new F, we move B down and to the right,maintaining the proportion 1-Sqrt(3)-2 Fourth.- What do you mean with” while preserving line segments inside each triangle”? Fifth.- What's the meaning of the whole construction?.

Comment: Sorry to be so unclear. Here are the answers to your questions. 1) The transformation is part of a larger project involving gnomonic mappings. 2) I think C is at (-sqrt(3), -1) so F should shift straight down. 3) If I understand right, yes, I agree. 4) I want a line segment residing inside ECF to be mapped to a line segment in the 30-60-90 triangle.  5) This construction is a step in a very involved project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can map $\triangle EBC$ to $\triangle EBC^\prime$ with a linear transformation $f(\mathbb{R}^2)\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$ which leaves every point of line $EB$ fixed and maps $B$ to $C^\prime$. However, it will not map $F$ to $F^\prime$ unless $F$ is the midpoint of segment $CB$.

For each point $X$ in $\triangle CEB$ the ray $BX$ intersects side $EC$ at some unique point $P$ and there is a unique number $s\in[0,1]$ such that

\begin{equation}
X=(1-s)B+sP \tag{1}
\end{equation}

For each $P$ of segment $EC$ there is a unique number $t\in[0,1]$ such that

\begin{equation}
P=(1-t)E+tC \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Thus for each point $X\in\triangle CEB$ there are unique $\triangle CEB$ coordinates $(s,t)$ for $X$ satisfying

\begin{equation}
X=(1-s)B+s(1-t)E+stC \tag{3}
\end{equation}

In  $\triangle CEC^\prime$ the diagram below, segment $CF^\prime$ is congruent to segment $F^\prime C^\prime$.

The transformation

\begin{equation}
f(X(s,t))=(1-s)C^\prime+s(1-t)E+stC \tag{4}
\end{equation}

maps $\triangle CEB$ to $\triangle CEC^\prime$ and maps each line segment in $\triangle CEB$ to a line segment in $\triangle CEC^\prime$. However, it does not map $F$ to $F^\prime$ (unless $F$ is the midpoint of $CB$). Instead it maps $F^\prime$ to some point $F^{\prime\prime}$ on segment $CC^\prime$.

There is no linear transformation $g\,:\triangle CEC^\prime\to\triangle CEC^\prime$ leaving the vertices of $\triangle CEC^\prime$ fixed while mapping $F^{\prime\prime}$ to $F^\prime$.
[image: Triangle transform]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, John! If I understand correctly, you are showing that there is no line preserving map of CEB to CEC' (which I appreciate). But did you also show that one cannot map ECF to ECF' and then map EBF to EC'F', and do so in such a way that points on EF' in the two triangles correspond? It would not preserve line segments, but rather turn them into two connected line segments. Sorry if that's a dumb question, but the lack of such a map seems very counter-intuitive. Thanks again!

Comment: The function $f(X(s,t))$ maps $\triangle CEB$ to $\triangle CEC^\prime$ and *does* preserve lines. I am about to leave for several hours and don't have a ready reply for the rest of your question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include the criteria that F gets mapped to F'. Cheers.

Comment: You can map any triangle in the plane to any other triangle in a way that preserves lines. But if you map $\triangle ECF$ to $\triangle ECF^\prime$ by a linear transformation it will map $B$ to some point $B^\prime\ne C^\prime$ on the line $CC^\prime$. You can then find a  linear transformation to map $\triangle CEB^\prime$ onto $CEC^\prime$ but unfortunately that transformation will move point $F^\prime$ so that $\angle EF^\prime C$ is no longer a right angle. So what you want to do cannot be done with a linear transformation.

Comment: Thanks John! One more question, if you don't mind. You said you could map any triangle in the plane to any other triangle in a way that preserves lines. What specific function f would map ECF to ECF' (ignoring the effects of f on EFB)? Then, completely separate problem, what function g would map EFB to EF'C' (ignoring the effects of g on anything outside of EFB)? I really appreciate your willingness to share your expertise!

Comment: @Brian Note that this process moves only one vertex at a time. To move two vertices such as triangle EFB to EF'C' requires the composition of two such transforms. To move triangle ECF to ECF^' replace $B$ in eqs(1),(3) with $F$ and replace $C^\prime$ in eq(4) with $F^\prime$. In eqs 1-4, $E$ and $C$ are the fixed vertices and $B$ is being moved; $E$ and $B$ are the *initial* vertices in the sense that $s=0$ at $B$ and $t=0$ at $E$. For $X\in\triangle CEB$ we have $s=BX/BP,\,t=EP/EC$.